# how to use HeidiSQL BLOB(hex code) in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I'm creating a website in which I want to displaying some images and I'm using JSP. I chose HeidiSQL for database. I was wondering if there is any way to store images in HeidiSQL and I found that there is BLOB. But when I upload any image in the BLOB column there appears some kind of hex code. So my question is what i've got to do with this hex code to take back the image and use it in my JSP.

Comment: HeidiSQL is **not** a database. It's a SQL _client_ application that connects **to** a database server. HeidiSQL can connect (use) Postgres, SQL Server or MySQL. Which one of those three are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The hex code is just for display purposes (otherwise it would take at least twice the storage). Since `BLOB` stores binary data, and not all bytes are displayable, it makes more sense to display the data as hex encoded to human readers.

When you read the `BLOB`, you'll get bytes out and you don't need to perform any conversion.